How do I fix my clogged sink with black flakes coming out?
My second floor sink in my bathroom is clogged and I have black flakes coming out every time I plunge it and the water doesn't go down. I don't know what to do to fix it. It's not happening anywhere else but that sink.

Start with a snake, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain_snake . If that fails to remove the blockage, likely a plumber is needed to fix it.

Have you taken apart the p-trap? That’ll help identify where the clog is and make using the snake easier.

BTW., if the black flakes are from a previous attempt to use a drain cleaner (e.g., Drano flakes, which contain aluminum that blackens), then you have a very dangerous situation, with caustic soda solution in that water. The water needs to be safely removed before trying to fix the issue!
